# About AngularJS $RouteParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started to learn AngularJS. When I use the `.service` of AngularJS, if I inject `$RouteParams`, but I don't actually use `$RouteParams`, then the `.service` doesn't work.

```
myApp.service('myService', function() {
    this.name = 'myServiceName';
    var self = this;
    this.nameLength = function () {
        return self.name.length;
    };  
});
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$log','$routeParams','myService',function($scope, $log,myService,$routeParams) {
    $scope.handle = myService.name;
}]);
```

What's weird is that if I do use `$RouteParams` in the controller, then it works, why would the `$RouteParams` influence the use of `.service`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `$routeParams` but the order of dependencies injected. Interchange the order of dependencies to be same as the annotated dependencies. In your code you have annotated the `$routeParams` service before `myService`: `['$scope','$log','$routeParams','myService'` but while using them in injected depndencies as callback function parameters you are using `$routeParams` after `myService`. When you try to use the `myService.name`, it actually refers to `$routeParams` which does not have a property named `name`. Change your code as below and it will work

```
myApp.service('myService',function(){
      this.name='myServiceName';
      var self=this;
      this.nameLength=function(){
            return self.name.length;
        };  
});

myApp.controller('mainController',  ['$scope','$log','$routeParams','myService',function($scope, $log,$routeParams, myService) {
   $scope.handle = myService.name;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya, it works! It's quite confusing for me how exactly AngularJs implements the dependency injection. I will keep on learning!

Answer (score 0):

Create your controllers like this. This way is less confusing and more readable.

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $log,myService,$routeParams) {
    $scope.handle = myService.name;
});
```

Comment: This is the 'Implicit Annotation'. Quote from [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di): 'Careful: If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.' It is not wrong, but not best practise.

Comment: Yeah.. That is the down side.

Answer (score 0):

Aditya Singh already explained this pretty well. To prevent this mistake, you could change code style to the following:

```
myApp.controller('mainController',
['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams', 'myService',
function($scope, $log, $routeParams, myService) {
    $scope.handle = myService.name;
}]);
```

This also prevents you from vertical scrolling when there are many injections in your controller.